# Can't delete or move item from trash using `sudo rm`, superuser account, or even single user mode

Tags: macos, finder, command-line, trash

At some point in the past I was messing around with the battery menu on my 2012 MacBook Pro running High Sierra to see if I could it to display the estimated time remaining rather than a percentage. Anywho, I created a copy of the file `/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Battery.menu` which I no longer needed, so I trashed it.

Since then I have been unable to move the item from the trash or delete it.

I have tried:

- deleting normally
- using the force delete option (option + delete)
- trying to drag item out of trash (makes a copy, which is deletable)
- running `sudo rm -vrf ~/.Trash/Battery.menu` (result: "Operation not permitted")
- renaming and moving the file with `sudo mv ~/.Trash/Battery.menu` (result: "Operation not permitted")
- running the above commands after `su` in Terminal
- using the root account to try the above
- booting into single user mode, mounting the file system, using above commands. (result: "Operation not permitted")
- using `setfile` to try to set the busy attribute to not busy and to unlock the file (though it is not locked) using `setfile -a z ~/.Trash/Battery.menu`. Result:
  "ERROR: Unexpected Error. (-5000)  on file: /Users/myuser/.Trash/Battery.menu"
- repairing permissions, then trying everything again
- booting into recovery, turning off SIP, and trying to delete again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a file I could not delete from Trash. Finally I moved it from the Trash back to the Desktop, which I have synced to iCloud. Then I was able to use the Files app on my iPhone to delete it.

Another path to pursue: boot to recovery and turn off SIP (until you get the file deleted.)

Comment: It can't be moved from the trash, only copied. But I will try the second option about turning of SIP!

Comment: I tried turning off SIP but sadly I am still unable to delete that file. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

## Recovery to delete?

I see you booted into recovery to disable SIP, but did you attempt the delete from the terminal *while in recovery mode?*
Any files that are not open/protected by the currently-running OS should be manageable.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a number of large macOS installers hogging valuable space, which would move to `~/.Trash` and back but otherwise only copy and acquire this icon in the process:

[image: crossed-out circle icon acquired by files and directories that can't be deleted]

After losing most of my hair over the matter, I stumbled upon several answers that said to go to Recovery Mode (Command+R during bootup) and temporarily disable `csrutil` (System Integrity Protection or SIP).

(Helpful hint: take all your problematic files and put them in a folder with a super-unique name like `xxxabc`, and drag *that folder* to the Trash. You'll see why this is useful in a second.)

Was getting ready to disable the SIP, but before that, just for kicks, while in Recovery Mode, I opened up a Terminal window and searched for my user name (so I could then access `~/.Trash`):

```
find / -iname '*mycurrentusernameinUsers*'
```

Once I located the specific path to my profile with the problematic indelible Trash contents, I changed to that directory using `cd`:

```
cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/mycurrentusernameinUsers
```

I'm now inside `~/.Trash` (`~` being a stand-in for `mycurrentusernameinUsers` AKA my home directory). Turns out that, while in Recovery Mode, I can `rm -rf` an undeletable folder here no problem.

As such, in bash, in Recovery Mode, this was the **FINAL FIX**, without having to disable the SIP:

```
rm -rf xxxabc
```

Full path:

```
rm -rf /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/mycurrentusernameinUsers/.Trash/xxxabc
```

(Your path may vary.)

Answer (score -1):

### Why aren't you allowed to delete that file?

As you are getting the "Operation Not Permitted" message, I can tell that the file is protected by the system and is therefore extremely hard to delete through normal deletion means (as you have tried).

You could normally run `sudo rm -rf Battery.menu` to delete this file but as mentioned above, it won't work.

### How to fix that error? (And delete the file)

To delete the unwanted file, run this command in Terminal :

```
sudo /System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helpers/bypass rm -rfv Battery.menu
```

This will bypass every restriction that are in place causing it to show the error shown above ("Operation Not Permitted") when running `sudo rm -rf Battery.menu`.

Note that "bypass" is still located in `/System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helpers/bypass` for me.